# I need to learn these piece of code written in c++

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, containers, unordered-map

I have a big piece code that is analyzing some things related to network.

I need to learn some parts of that code. but I couldn't understand the following part. I don't know such a usage.

```
unordered_map < string, DomainInfo *>::iterator hostTrafficItr;
```

As far as I know `unordered_map` gets a key, map pair and contains it (a container).

Comment: The code declares an iterator with the name `hostTrafficItr` for `std::unordered_map` the *types* stored by your unordered map are `string` and `DomainInfo *`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You are welcome to ask good questions here. Please avoid salutations and taglines(http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) in your posts. Also please refer other sections in the FAQ(stackoverflow.com/faq) regarding how to use this site.

Comment: thank u Alok, ur answer is really helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is declaration of (probably standard) unorderd_map (see here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/) iterator.

unordered_map is key->value structure allowing to access DomainInfo* element using string to identify them.

The iterator is a class allowing you to (as the name says) iterate through collection elements providing you access to collections keys and values.

You can access key connected with current iterator value using:

```
hostTrafficItr->first //Has type string
```

and value using

```
hostTrafficItr->second //Has type DomainInfo*
```

dereference operator returns pair<string, DomainInfo>.

Iterators are most common initialized by .begin() or .end() of the collection.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Your `unordered_map` has a key of type `string`, and value of type `DomainInfo*`. `::iterator` declares `hostTrafficItr` as an [iterator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/) to this map type.

It may be a good idea to read a good C++ reference book. If you need an online reference, you could use this: http://www.cplusplus.com/

Comment: @tusherity It is not nice to accept one answer and then accept another answer. Wait until you get enough answers before you pick one. Also, the link to the references I have given you answers all your questions. SO is not a substitute for reading a good book.

Comment: sorry about that:(
i will be more careful about that